# sql statement isnt saving any data into table

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, insert-into

Whenever I execute my C# code everything goes well, no compiler errors, nothing. 
But when I go to look at my table in the server explorer, nothing was inserted. 
Restarted Visual Studio, still nothing.

I went to debug and I looked at the `cmd` string before it executes `ExecuteNonQuery()` and the string still is `@itmId,...` etc. Not sure if that would effect it or not. Any help?

```
try
{
    Item workingItem = mItemList.Items[itemCombo.SelectedIndex - 1] as Item;
    SqlCeConnection sc = new SqlCeConnection(SalesTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.salesTrackerConnectionString);
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Sales VALUES(@itmId, @itmNm,@fstNm, @date,@prft, @commision)", sc);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itmId", workingItem.ItemId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itmNm", workingItem.ItemName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fstNm", logedSalesmen.ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prft", workingItem.Profit);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commision", workingItem.Commision);
    sc.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sc.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Save successfull");
    this.Close();
} 
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
```

EDIT:So it is a matter of the temporary debug database being used, i used select count(0) to figure that out. But im not sure what i should use in my connection string to fix it.

Comment: Can you show us your **connection string**?!?!

Comment: The string won't change, parameters are sent to the database separately without being parsed into the sql string at the client.(btw, for two good reasons: db can cache the query plan and for better protection against sql-injection)

Comment: What happens if you step through that section of code.

Comment: Do you end in the catch or does it succesfully exceute?

Comment: offtopic... been question 100k on SQL tag deserves at least one upvote XD

Comment: Can you show us your connection string?!?!

Comment: did you try removing the @ signs used in the variables in your insert query??

Comment: @Hasitha Those are not just @ symbols. Those are parameters. This is a parameterized SQL query.

Comment: @isuru i know but i have been working with mysql stored procedures, and i use the @ sign only on my program code, but in the sql i use the same variable without the @ sign..thot it might be the same with sql

Comment: I executed the non paremterized sql statement using the server explorer on the database and it worked fine

Comment: I don't use c# but don't you need a commit somewhere, or is autocommit specified in your connection properties.

Comment: My connection string is Data Source=C:\Users\Phil\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SalesTracker\SalesTracker\salesTracker.sdf

Comment: I was under the assumption that executeNonQuery did commit it, as non of the code i found on google suggested otherwise.

Comment: Have a look at your database logs to see what is actually arriving in the database. If nothing, then maybe a (auto) commit is missing.

Comment: @Ukemi - unless you've seen it documented I wouldn't make that assumption. Add a commit and see what happens.

Comment: Im semi new to databases, and im using sql compact 3.5, im not sure how to check my database logs

Comment: hows that, i dont use transations.

Comment: I would then suggest you replace all variables with hard coded values, just to test. If that works, then - one by one - add in your parameters until you see where the problem lies.

Comment: So it is a matter of the temporary debug database being used, i used select count(0) to figure that out. But im not sure what i should use in my connection string to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common error here is actually a *deployment* thing - i.e. having 2 different database files in play. In particular, commonly the database file you are debugging (etc) against is often the one in "bin/debug" or similar, and gets overwritten every time you build. But the file people often look at to see the change is the one in their project tree.

Make sure you are looking at the right file.

The code looks fine; the fact that the parameters are still parameters is entirely expected and correct. If you want a simple way of validating the insert, then just check

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Sales
```

before and after the insert; I expect it will be incrementing.

Also check that you are closing and disposing the connection cleanly (in case this is simply a buffered change that didn't get written before the process terminated). Both `sc` and `cmd` are `IDisposable`, so you should use `using` really:

```
using(SqlCeConnection sc = new SqlCeConnection(
    SalesTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.salesTrackerConnectionString))
using(SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(
    "INSERT INTO Sales VALUES(@itmId, @itmNm,@fstNm, @date,@prft, @commision)",
    sc))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itmId", workingItem.ItemId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itmNm", workingItem.ItemName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fstNm", logedSalesmen.ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",
        DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prft", workingItem.Profit);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commision", workingItem.Commision);
    sc.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: So i tried directly pasting the connection string, and i got a different error, Format of the initialization string does not conform to the specification starting at index 0, im going to google it see where i get

EDIT: I just screwed up the new connection string, i fixed it. I now have a completely unparameterized string, using nothing more than "Data Source=salesTracker.sdf" as my connection string, still cant seem to save the data

Comment: I just screwed up the new connection string, i fixed it. I now have a completely unparameterized string, using nothing more than "Data Source=salesTracker.sdf" as my connection string, still cant seem to save the data

Comment: So the Select Count thing does work as you described but im just not sure how to fix it, what should i put in my connection string?

Comment: @Ukemi well that depends: where is the file?

Comment: in my datadirectory, my connection string reads from the database just fine using Data Source="SalesTracker.sdf"

Comment: I guess my much more specific thing is i dont want to use the copied version of my database, i want to use the legit version of my database.

Comment: @Ukemi then your connection string must point it to that explicitly; I'm not a huge expert on CE connection strings, but you should be able to check which file got edited just from the audit information (last-updated on the file, etc)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't convert `DateTime.Now` to a string - pass it just as `DateTime.Now`

You should specify the columns in your insert statement: Ie:

```
INSERT INTO Sales (ItemID,ItemName...) VALUES (@itmID)
```

You can use SQL Profiler to check what is being passed to the Database.

Comment: The DateTime.now thing works fine, but it still doesnt commit any data to the database, and there is no SQL profiler for sql compact edition

Comment: Have you tried putting the column names into the insert statement?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio can sometimes copy SQLCE databases when you don't want it to, when you build your C# project. So, click on the sdf file in the Solution Explorer and select Copy if newer.